# Why does the Network tab show the information sent as POST?

Tags: php, html, post

I have a `sign in` form, and the `SIGN IN` button sends the information to a file named `members.php` to perform the signing in.

All of this is implemented with the `POST` method. Still, when i click `SIGN IN`, i can see the information in the `Network` tab. Is that ok or is it considered to be a bug?

Comment: It is Ok. That's how things sometimes get *debugged*.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the information needs to be transmitted somehow, doesn't it? "POST" does not stand for "telepathically transport data without anyone noticing". The only thing it means that the data is transferred in the HTTP body instead of the URL. POST was never meant to and did never "hide" anything.